# windows linux duabl boot cannot access windows (CSM)

Tags: dual-boot

This post wont be organized, in a real panic, promise to rewrite it tomorrow.
Have a samsung laptop, installed Linux Ubuntu latest version dual boot with windows. I remember that i read a comment about the csm/uefi option, followed the tutorial, cant remember what option i chose back then. 
My battery died, and when it happens it always changes the "csm/uefi option".
i changed it to CSM, used Linux for a couple of days. Tried accessing windows, it just loaded infinitely, tried accessing the volume in Linux gave an error message

```
"Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/jonathan/309A81959A81586C: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda2" "/media/jonathan/309A81959A81586C"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."
```

Tried changing back to uefi mode but right after restarting theres a black screen with white text saying "all boot options are tried, press f4 to reset factory settings" (something like that)

it only start with uefi and csm // csm and only linux.

I have unbacked 23 year worth of family pictures there... please help

Comment: Did you try mounting the volume read-only?  If you can mount it that way, do you have a USB/writeable CDROM to immediately back up your files?  (They are probably OK, don't panic.)

Comment: mounted right now, it let me open the files (THANX A LOT)
problem though is that there is like 300 GB of photos, no solution other than copy them all? (btw, can i shut down my pc so i can go buy an external harddrive in the meantime?)

Comment: You should be able to shutdown without problem.  Other solutions are possible, but who knows what damage a typo may cause -- backup your files first is the safest approach.  More information would be useful, like which Ubuntu, which Windows, disk partitioning type (DOS or GPT) for any recommendation on the fix.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/